# UWP Background Task Trigger for Power Events

Tags: c#, uwp, triggers, background-task

I have a UWP application that needs to perform a log task for every system start/resume/suspend/shutdown.

Is there a way I could do this task with a background task?
From the [MS documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background), there seems to be no sort of trigger for such events.

I currently have a service that does this, and access to the service from the UWP could be performed, but the service will not be packaged along with the UWP app so it might not be the best solution right now.

Comment: you can catch the start/resume/suspend/shutdown event in `app.xaml.cs` file so you just need to create a service through which you can add current application log

Comment: you can refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) in which you can see the UWP application life cycle. for launch you just need to copy the OnLaunched event from given [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-app-prelaunch) and paste it to app.xaml.cs file.now call your service in OnLaunched event which can add the application launch state to database. do same for other events.

Comment: @ketan I understand that this lifecycle is meant for the UWP app itself. But what I want to listen to are more of system power events (i.e. shutdown the computer, put it to sleep, etc...)

Comment: As you said, there seems to be no sort of trigger for such events, so if you want to achieve through the background task, it is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about what you asking for but if you just want to execute background task you can use :

```
using System.Threading;

namespace yourNamespace
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void main()
        {
            Thread thread = new thread(Task);
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void Task()
        {
            //What you want to do
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is a UWP out-of-process background task. It runs in a separate process than your app's process.

Comment: If you want to have a seperate process why did you not just make a new app who take arguments and execute the task you want to do ? Then execute the new app from your primary one ?

Comment: The problem is my UWP is not supposed to be open all the time (hence, runs a background task with a certain trigger event). Native UWP apps can't have invisible windows, that is why I am hoping to figure out a way to catch these system power events on the out-of-process background task. These background tasks get registered into the system, and will run all the time even if the app is closed.